# for loop in R with the elastic package

Tags: r, elasticsearch

I have a vector with user ID's  userIds(class - integer):

```
873611  875908  876399  877630  878295  878794  880618  881646
```

And a code:

```
aggs <- '{
  "size": 10000, 
  "filter": {
    "term": {
      "user_id": "593586" #<- there will be all user ids
    }
  },
  "sort": [{
    "@timestamp": { "order": "asc" }
  }] 
}'
tablTogether = Search(index="fort", body=aggs, asdf = TRUE)
```

I need to create a loop of this code with all users id's.

something like this:

```
 for (int i = 0; i<userIds.lengths; i++)
{
aggs <- '{
"size": 10000, 
"filter": {
"term": {
  "user_id": "+userIds[i]+" #<- Is it right?
}
},
"sort": [{
"@timestamp": { "order": "asc" }
 }] 
 }'
 tablTogether = Search(index="fort", body=aggs, asdf = TRUE)
 }
```

How to translate this code to R. Thx for helping me!!!

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! I've reformatted your code so it's a bit more visually appealing to someone who could answer you. You might want to edit by yourself to include more detail on what you want your loop to actually do, so as not to keep us guessing. Good luck!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i'm the author of the `elastic` package - so hopefully I can help :/

Here's a way to do it with a for loop

```
aggs <- '{
  "size": 10000, 
  "filter": {
    "term": {
      "user_id": "%s"
    }
  },
  "sort": [{
    "@timestamp": { "order": "asc" }
  }] 
}'
out = list()
for (i in seq_along(users)) {
  out[[i]] <- Search(index = "fort", 
                     body = sprintf(aggs, users[i]), 
                     asdf = TRUE)
}
```

Let me know if that works.

Comment: Yeah it works!!! Nice job with elastic!!!THX