# elastic call and loops/apply in R

Tags: r, loops, apply, lapply, elasticsearch

How do I run a loop/apply that will run an elastic search call with a different body each time?

I need to query (filtered query) an index for the word "local" for let's see, 2000 to 2010 and I want to store the results in R. Here I made an example with years from 2000 to 2001. I tried with paste but it wouldn't work because it messes up the JSON language in the body part. I can't share the es_base, unfortunately, but I would appreciate any help.

Thanks!

```
library(elastic)
connect(es_base = "http://...", es_port = "")

years <- list(
    b <-'{
    "query": {
    "filtered": {
    "query": {"term": { "signature_year": 2000}},
    "filter": {
    "term": { "text": "local"}
      }
     }
    }
  }',
   c <- '{
    "query": {
    "filtered": {
    "query": {"term": { "signature_year": 2001}},
    "filter": {
    "term": { "text": "local"}
        }
       }
      }
     }'
     )


    a<-for(i in years) {
          Search( index = "index", b = i)$hits$total
            }
```

Comment: Solved: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32551526/for-loop-in-r-with-the-elastic-package

Comment: glad it's sorted, let me know if you run into any other problems at  https://github.com/ropensci/elastic